# How do I avoid "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" error on my application?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make upload file part and I got an issue like when I upload csv file and the first component has got error and when I upload file on another component it doesn't get error

and the error is like this :

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

my website is working fine, however I'm worrying the error would make it bad

`info` state is for uploading file .

and i need to upload file each components at `Parent component`
but i'm using it in Child component  and it works fine except that error

I assume that `info` state is making the issue .

I'd like to know how to avoid that error

Thank you in advance

and my code is like this:

### Parent Component :

```
const eachComponent = (index, id) => (
    <DataSide id={id} key={index} onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu
        panelNum={index + 1}
        show={show[index]}
        chart={chart[index]}
        changeLayout={changeLayout}
      />
      {ChangeableType(index + 1).map(
        (id, idx) =>
          chart[index].key === id.key && ChangeableType(index + 1)[idx]
      )}
      {BarTypes(index).map(
        (id, idx) => chart[index].key === id.key && BarTypes(index)[idx]
      )}
      {/* {LineTypes(index).map(
        (id, idx) => chart[index].key === id.key && LineTypes(index)[idx]
      )}
      {GridTypes(index).map(
        (id, idx) => chart[index].key === id.key && GridTypes(index)[idx]
      )} */}
    </DataSide>
  );

  const layout = [
    eachComponent(0, "first"),

    eachComponent(1, "second"),

    eachComponent(2, "third"),

    eachComponent(3, "fourth"),
```

### and Child component :

```
const CsvFile = ({ match, location }) => {
  const { panelNum, changeLayout } = location.state;
  const chart = location.data;
  const { Plugins, DataContextUseState } = useContext(DataContextApi);
  const [plugins, setPlugins] = Plugins;
  const [DataContext, setDataContext] = DataContextUseState;

  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
   ///this info is the cause as i guess 
  
  
  
  const history = useHistory();

  const [y, setY] = useState();
  const [x, setX] = useState();

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
```

This is the Child component of second one that I'm using `info` state :

```
const CsvFileReader = ({ setInfo }) => {
  const handleOnDrop = data => {
    const infos = data.map(item => item.data);
    setTimeout(() => setInfo([...infos]), 1000);
  };

  const handleOnError = (err, file, inputElem, reason) => {
    console.log(err);
  };

  const handleOnRemoveFile = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MainReader>
        <CSVReader
          onDrop={handleOnDrop}
          onError={handleOnError}
          config={
            (({ fastMode: true }, { chunk: "LocalChunkSize" }),
            { header: false })
          }
          addRemoveButton
          onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
        >
```

Comment: Reproducing this in a sandbox would make it a heck of a lot easier to troubleshoot, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a timeout to update state, possibly after the component has unmounted. Use a react ref to store a reference to the current timeout and clear it when the component unmounts.

```
const CsvFileReader = ({ setInfo }) => {
  const timerRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current); // clear any running timeouts
  }, []);

  const handleOnDrop = data => {
    const infos = data.map(item => item.data);
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => setInfo([...infos]), 1000); // save timeout ref
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ref` to check component is unmounted or not in `CsvFileReader` component

```
const ref = useRef()

const handleOnDrop = data => {
  const infos = data.map(item => item.data);
  setTimeout(() => ref.current && setInfo([...infos]), 1000);
};

return (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <MainReader>
```